# I need an app code to be corrected. The app displays spectrogram but there is an error that it does not allow plotting bigger spectrograms

Tags: android

I need an app code to be corrected. The app displays spectrogram but there is an error that it does not allow plotting bigger spectrograms.

and I get an error W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (32768x1, max=16384x16384).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The error message is pretty clear, actually. Maybe you should break the bitmap into two smaller portions.

Comment: `Bitmap too large`. You need a smaller Bitmap

Answer (score 0):

Try compressing the `Bitmap`, example:-

```java
//This is to get the bitmap from resources
Bitmap bitmap = (BitmapDrawable) getResources()
    .getDrawable(R.drawable.imageBitmap)).getBitmap();

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 25, out);
// Now the bitmap is compressed and use 'bitmap' anywhere
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need a proper app code for this error.